# How can you use vectors and int's as constructors for a class

Tags: c++, constructor

If I had a class foo then

```
class foo{
   vector <int> vec;
   int someint;

   public:
   foo(number n): someint(n){}


}
```

How would I write a constructor for the `vector`, for `class foo`? Moreoever, I can use:

```
int get_someint() const{

  return someint;
}
```

To return an `int`, but what about vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with complex data types, its usually best to work with references, or const-references like so:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()  {}  // default construct of A, v_ is empty

    A(const std::vector<int>& source)
      : v_(source)  // construct A, given a vector that is 
                    // copied into v_
    {
    }

    // returns an immutable reference to v_
    const std::vector<int>& get_v() const
    {
       return v_;
    }

    // returns a mutable reference to v_
    std::vector<int>& get_v()
    {
        return v_;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
};
```

Example usage:

```
A a_no_vec;  // A has an empty vector v_

std::vector<int> src;

src.push_back(16);
src.push_back(19);

A a_with_vec(src);  // A has a vector that is a copy of src
```

Comment: Your constructor should take `source` in by reference. You are creating an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @OscarKorz If I wanted to print the vector out using cout, would I use cout << a_with_vec.get_v() << '\n' ?

Comment: Theoretically yes. The STL doesn't provide `operator<<(ostream&, const vector<T>&)` though, so unless you've written it, no.

Comment: @OscarKorz Then how can I print the vector using STL, also using a_no_vec.push_back(10); doesn't seem to work because its not a member function. It makes sense, but I thought I could the <vector> member functions buy including it? Thanks.

Comment: @cody `a_no_vec` is not a `vector`, it's an `A`. Try `a_no_vec.get_v().push_back(10);`. As for printing, you'll need to iterate over the container and print the values individually.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it makes sense now. 1 last question though, if I'm using an immutable reference to v_ for my get_v, then how can I push_back() a value into the vector. Doing so would be changing a constant value right? SO if I use A a_no_vec and use a_no_vec.get_v().push_back(10); then I would get an error saying that I'm changing a const value.How can I push_back into the vector without modifying the const. Thanks!

Comment: In this case since we provide functions to get a const-reference as well as a reference (non const), the compiler will chose what is appropriate.  `a_no_vec.get_v().push_back(...)` in this context will call the non-const version and should work properly.  If you already hold your `A` as const, then you will not be able to call non-const functions, but that isn't the case in the small example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just the same. For all purposes, consider `vector<int>` as a normal variable (like an `int`, for example), so you can write:

```
class foo{
   vector <int> vec;
   int someint;

   public:
   foo(number n, vector<int> v): someint(n), vec(v){}
}
```

It will be copied inside and out, and that may mean a lot of memory copies. This is why for such large objects, pass by reference (either by pointer or reference) is used. For example, to return the vector:

```
vector<int> const& the_vector()
{ return inner_vector; } // no copy
```

and the constructor would be also `foo(number n, vector<int> const& v)`. Also, if internally you don't have to store a copy of the vector, you can use a pointer or reference to that vector as a member, instead of the vector copy itself, that is, the class being:

```
class foo{
   vector <int>& vec;
   int someint;

   public:
   foo(int n, vector<int>& v): someint(n), vec(v){}
}
```

(note the references). The same with pointers.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. However, how would I use the class type foo as an object in int main. If I had to specify int then in main i could write: foo bar(1); . This would initialize someint to 1 right? How can I initialize the vector the same way but fill it with ints?

Comment: In C++ alone (not C++11) there is no way of filling a vector with a construct. You have to create it, fill it, then pass it to the foo object. `vector<int> v(2); v[0]=1; v[1]=2; foo my_foo(3,v)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a constructor for the vector. Vector already has it's constructors. Also you can simply return a vector as you return your int e.g.

```
const std::vector<int> & getVec()
{
   return vec;
}
```